# Run spark-submit with my own build of hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to run spark 2.02 with a snapshot of hadoop 2.8. I'm using `spark-2.0.2-bin-without-hadoop` from the website. I built hadoop 2.8 using [these directions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/08/02/compile-and-build-specific-hadoop-source-code-branch-using-azure-vm/). Per the spark website, prior to running `spark-submit` I call:

`export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/path/to/hadoop2.8/bin/hadoop classpath)`

I call spark-submit as follows

```
spark-submit --verbose --master mesos://$MASTER_HOST/mesos
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.handle(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitOptionParser.parse(SparkSubmitOptionParser.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

Is there some argument to spark-submit where I can specify the location of hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting HADOOP_HOME to the location of your Hadoop binaries.

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/path/to/hadoop"
```