# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when deploying my program using spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am writing a program to upload a data to some s3a:// link. The program is compiled through `mvn install`. Running the program locally (as in using `java -jar jarfile.jar`) returned no error. However, when I use spark-submit (as in using `spark-submit jarfile.jar`), it returned such error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.addDeprecatedKeys(S3AFileSystem.java:181)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.(S3AFileSystem.java:185)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           ...

The error log traced to this portion of my source code:

```
sparkDataset
        .write()
        .format("parquet")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .save("some s3a:// link");
```

where `sparkDataset` is an instance of `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`.

Trying [How to access s3a:// files from Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385981/how-to-access-s3a-files-from-apache-spark) is unsuccessful and returned another error as such:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/fs/GlobalStorageStatistics$StorageStatisticsProvider

Problem from [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158612/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hadoop-conf-configuration-reloadexisting) is also unlikely because I can run locally, in which the compatilibity is not a problem.

In addition, these are the version of related libraries that I used:

- aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.199
- hadoop-aws:3.0.0

I am expecting files written through the s3a:// links. I think dependency is not the issue because I can run locally. I only face this problem when using spark-submit to run this program. Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Edit: In addition, I have checked that the spark version of the spark submit is said to be built for hadoop 2.7 and above. I am strictly using hadoop 3.0.0. Could this be a clue for why such error happened in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Run spark-submit with my own build of hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666508/run-spark-submit-with-my-own-build-of-hadoop) had seem to guide me on finding my own solution.

Based on my understanding, for some unknown reason*, the spark-submit provided by the distribution 'spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz' will exclude any packages of hadoop that is compiled together in your application.

The reason why was the `NoSuchMethodError` error raised is because the method `reloadExistingConfiguration` does not exist until Hadoop version 2.8.x. It seemed that writing a parquet would somehow invoke this particular method along the way.

My solution is to use the separate distribution of 'spark-2.4.0-without-hadoop.tgz' while connecting it to hadoop 3.0.0 so that it will use the correct version of hadoop even if spark-submit excluded the packages in your application during execution.

In addition, since the packages would be excluded by spark-submit anyway, I would not create a fat jar during compilation through Maven. Instead, I would use the flag `--packages` during execution to specify the dependencies that is required to run my application.

Comment: *unknown reason is due to my limited knowledge of spark engine and their usage in general production